# how to create a repository in GitHub

Tags: git, github, repository, project, repository-pattern

I'm relatively new to GitHub and version control, and I'm looking for guidance on creating a repository. Could someone provide step-by-step instructions on creating a repository on GitHub? I'm interested in both command line and GUI methods. Any additional tips or best practices would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the existing GitHub repo to your local computer.
2. Create a brand-new GitHub repo with a new name.
3. Upload the existing code repo files to your brand-new repo.